# JavaScript preloader for particular div content

Tags: javascript, html

I need to remove `loader gif` once the particular `div` content is loaded.

I tried using this but it is loading entire website then the `loader gif` is removed.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#banner_loader").addClass("displaynone");
});
```

Comment: You can check if the `.height()` of your `div` changes and than remove the loader.

Comment: I have a fixed height of this div :(

Comment: what about `$(yourdivID).load()` instead of `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: How about checking for a div or other elements height in your fixed height div?

Comment: @MarkWalters That solution is not working :(

Comment: Poor in JavaScript can you please help me to know how i can achieve that? @Ex-iT

Comment: Try making a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) with your code. Is the content in the your particular `div` loaded with AJAX? if that is the case you can use a callback there to hide the loader.

Answer (score 0):

You can put script in the div that will execute when the div has loaded, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9rk5c/)

```
<div>
    <script>
        $("#banner_loader").addClass("displaynone");
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you put the script in the div that you are waiting for, and the gif is in an element with id "banner_loader"?

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX for loading `div` content you can use [.ajaxStart()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#banner_loader").show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#banner_loader").hide();
});
```